# y-axis interval with dollar sign

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code to generate the a chart showing year in the x-axis, and the dollar amount in the y-axis. How can I format my y-axis to show intervals like $4,000,000, $8,000,000, $12,000,000...

Right now, the y-axis are showing 0.2, 0.4, and 1e7 on the left-top.

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    ...
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
    plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
    plt.ylabel('Amount')
    ...
    plt.savefig(img_path)
```

Comment: Show us your plot.

Comment: Look at this page: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html

Comment: Why is the question tagged `matlab`?

Answer (score 0):

**Matlab Example**

```
% Years on x axis
x = 2010:2016;

% Dollar amount on y axis
y = linspace(4000000,8000000,length(x));

% Plot and save the tick values that Matlab generates
plot(x,y);
yTicks = get(gca,'YTick');

% Turn ticks into non-exponential values
a = textscan(num2str(yTicks),'%f');

% Format into strings representing dollar amount with delimiter etc. 
newYTickLabels = Sep1000Str(a{1});

% Set your new ticklabels
set(gca,'YTickLabel',newYTickLabels)
```

Where `Sep1000Str()` is:

```
function output = Sep1000Str(a)
n = length(a);
for k = 1:n
    S = sprintf('$%.2f', a(k));
    S(2, length(S) - 6:-3:2) = ',';
    S = {transpose(S(S ~= char(0)))};
    output(k) = S;
end
```

Comment: is this in python?

Comment: I think it's in Matlab, as he mentioned

Comment: I hope this solves your problem, @user1187968. If so, please upvote and accept answer. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use the matplotlib FormatStrFormatter**

```
x_values = [2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017] #list of years
y_values = np.linspace(4e6,10e6,len(x_values)) #y_values with same size as x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax.plot(x_values, y_values)

formatter = ticker.FormatStrFormatter('$%0.1f') #declaring the formatter with the $ sign and y_values with 1 decimalplace
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label1.set_visible(True) #make your yvalues visible on the plot

plt.show()
```